# open link from mail in browser, without switching to the browser

Tags: chromium, email, thunderbird

In Thunderbird, I used to click on links, which resulted in an new tab, opened in the browser, without switching/activating the browser, so I could open 4, 5 mail notifications in a row, having 4, 5 associated entries in a forum opened, and change then to the browser to read the postings one by one.

Now I switched from Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, where my internet navigator is again chromium-browser, but now every link not only activates the browser, but pulls it from workspace 3, where the open browser is located, to working space 4, where the mail client is located.

Comment: Did you try middle-click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried some of those tips, but they didn't work in my environment:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Thunderbird/comments/7amm15/open_links_in_background/

The config editor in Thunderbird is now in Edit -> Preferences -> first tab "General"; scroll all the way down and click on "Config Editor".

Maybe you are luckier than me with any of those tips from Reddit.

Comment: FF: about:config: I changed "browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground" (or similar) to TRUE, the same for the same without "diverted". Seems to work. Now I need the equivalent for chromium, too. :)